# Adding and showing validation in AngularJS ui.grid for ui.grid.edit on a cell

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have an AngularJS application utilizing ui.grid. I want to enable and show validation errors when editing a cell. I believe this can be implemented via "editableCellTemplate".

Here is what I have in my `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs` for the editable cell in question:

```
{ 
  field: 'label',
  enableCellEdit: true,
  editableCellTemplate: 
    '<input type="text" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.index" ng-input="COL_FIELD" ng-model="COL_FIELD" name="label" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10" required />' +
    '<span class="error" ng-show="label.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>'
  },
```

So as is probably apparent above I'm not sure how to link the span's `ng-show` up to my cell's edit input.  Using Inspect Element I can see the `ng-invalid-minlength` class being added to the `input`, and the cell does turn red.  So the validation is firing; I can't see the span shown. How can I show it?

Answer (score 2):

With ui-grid 3.0 RC19, the editableCellTemplate approach is right. I recommend to you to copy from ui-grid.js directly, where the 'ui-grid/cellEditor' $templateCache is defined:

```
   $templateCache.put('ui-grid/cellEditor',
       "<div><form name=\"inputForm\"><input type=\"INPUT_TYPE\" ng- class=\"'colt' + col.uid\" ui-grid-editor ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\"></form> </div>");
```

And then, modified it to include it in your code:

```
   { 
      field: 'label',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      editableCellTemplate: 
      "<div><form name=\"inputForm\"><input type=\"INPUT_TYPE\" ng-class=\"'colt' + col.uid\" ui-grid-editor ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\" name=\"label\" ng-minlength=\"3\" ng-maxlength=\"10\" required validate-required-cell></form></div><span class=\"error\" ng-show=\"inputForm.$valid\">Too short!</span>"
    },
```

In my case I needed an aditional directive named validateRequiredField to stop the cell to close when the element lost focus:

```
  angularStartDirectives.directive('validateRequiredCell', function(uiGridEditConstants) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            element.bind('blur', function(evt) {

              if (scope.inputForm && !scope.inputForm.$valid) {

                // Stops the rest of the event handlers from being executed
                evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
              }

            });

        }
    };
});
```

You can also include styling like this:

```
  form input.ng-invalid {

      border-color:red;
  }

  form input.ng-valid {

     border-color: transparent;
  }
```

References for further improvement:

[UI Grid Validation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/angular/ui$20grid$20cell$20validation/angular/lYO9T3KjcbE/e7rTX3Z0X_QJ)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971767/how-to-add-individual-cell-validation-in-ui-grid-angularjs/32973058#32973058 as I found this answer to be buggy.

Answer (score 2):

In the code of Aquiles is a minor typing error. The error message should be displayed if there is no error.

It should be like:

```
ng-show=\"!inputForm.$valid\"
```

(this is a reply to the answer of Aquiles, but I'm missing reputation for direct commenting)

Greetings: Makarius