# How to add Individual Cell Validation in Ui-Grid Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to validate a value of an editable cell in ui grid and display the error. For example `Required`, `Max-Length`, `Min-Length` and etc.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellnav></div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addUser()">Add row</button>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've inserted your code into the post, as links tend to die. StackOverflow has its own built-in HTML/CSS/Javascript code snippet tool, so I'm using that.

Answer (score 3):

you could use the property editableCellTemplate of the the columnDef of your column to create your own html template for cell edit with the needed validations.
Example of cell validation with custom cell template :

```
{field: 'company', displayName: 'Company', enableColumnMenu: false,editableCellTemplate:
        "<div><form name=\"inputForm\"><input type=\"INPUT_TYPE\" ng-class=\"'colt' + col.uid\" ui-grid-editor ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\"  minlength=3 maxlength=10 required></form></div>"}
```

**Updated pluncker with displaying the error message** : [pluncker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Pvc4UYKSf71pIC2XrpY?p=preview)

to do the validation for all columns, you have to use the same editableCellTemplate for each column.

Comment: we want to add validator for all the 4 fields, if its possible to add <form> tag for all the 4 fields, Then may be 4 <form> tags. And also we want to display validation error messages on the field itself.

Comment: Is there a way to bind custom validation. I would like to bind a method on say `ng-keydown` to check the input against my set of rules.. How can that be done. I trying calling a `$scope` function on ng-change and that didn't work

Comment: I tried this `ng-change="grid.appScope.checkValidaton($event,MODEL_COL_FIELD,true,true)`. The scope function gets called however the `arguments` are undefined. How can I pass the `$event` and `ng-model` along

Comment: Much appreciated!  I was able to get this to work using <div ng-form="inputForm"><input... instead of the form element.